# Knockout setTimeout delay

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When a user logs into my website, I store a "logged in until" parameter on my server for that user, which is updated each time they interact with the server.  So if they are inactive for X seconds, they should be logged out and the page on their client refreshed to show the login screen.  Everything works nicely except the function keeps calling itself at 1 second intervals, and not the 1700+ second interval I'm looking for.  As each call hits the server, I don't want this to keep running more often than it needs to.

This function is contained within my knockout viewmodel.  logoutTimer is declared as a global variable.  Watching the console log I can see the delay shows the correct time, but it seems to be running about every 1 second.

```
self.autoLoginCheck = function() {
    clearTimeout(logoutTimer);
    //If not, refresh the main screen => that'll push them to the login screen automatically
    myurl = "/api/checkLoginStatus.php";
    var parameters = {
                        'userPublicID':self.userInfo().userPublicID
                    }
    $.post(myurl, parameters, function(data) {
        var getResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        if (getResponse.loggedIn < 1 ) {
            //This is the log out condition
            location.reload(true);
        } else {
            //Check how many more seconds the current log in is good for, that's when we'll check it again
            var msdelay = getResponse.nextCheck * 1000;
            console.log("Delay is " + msdelay);
            logoutTimer = setTimeout(self.autoLoginCheck(), msdelay);
        }
    });
}
```

I know this type of question has been asked many times, but reading all those answers I can't see why this function is running every second and not waiting 30 minutes.  Thanks to whoever shows me the obvious!

Comment: You need to pass the setTimeout function a function, not the response to a function. 
logoutTimer = setTimeout(self.autoLoginCheck, msdelay);

Comment: @JamesSutherland You should probably post that as an answer so OP can accept it and others landing here can easily spot the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to setTimeout should be a function, not the result of a function.

```
logoutTimer = setTimeout(self.autoLoginCheck, msdelay);
```